# React image onLoad, image preload

Tags: javascript, reactjs, изображения, lazyloading

Есть картинка на первом экране страницы, при медленном интернете вместо картинки ничего нет (пустое белое пространство в высоту картинки). Нужно до полной загрузки картинки показывать какую-нибудь анимацию, **как отловить полную загрузку картинки**?

```
 <img
    className={classes.image}
    src="/images/vacancies/image.png"
    alt="image"
    onLoad={() => console.log('loaded')} // Это не срабатывает
  />
```

Пока использую:

```
  useEffect(() => {
    setIsLoaded(true)
  }, [])
```

И в зависимости от значения **isLoaded** показываю либо картинку, либо заглушку.
Этот способ не спасает от частичной загрузки изображения при медленном интернете (сначала появляется заглушка, потом - белый фон, потом сверху вниз по чуть-чуть отрисовывается отображение).

**Как отображать изображение сразу после его загрузки** (сначала появляется заглушка, потом появляется полное изображение)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Это не так просто, но и не так сложно.
Для того чтобы показать картинку только после загрузки

1. Надо ее загрузить используя **fetch** или любой другой загрузчик
2. Пока ждем ответа показываем анимацию
3. После того как картинка загрузилась преобразовываем ее с помощью **blob** и **createObjectURL** в урл
4. Вставляем урл в атрибут src

```js
const { useEffect, useState } = React;

const Img = () => {
  const [url, setUrl] = useState('');
  useEffect(() => {
    fetch('https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1490730141103-6cac27aaab94')
      .then(response => response.blob())
      .then((image) => {
        setUrl(URL.createObjectURL(image));
      });
  });
  
  if (!url) {
    return 'animations...';
  }
      
  return <img src = {url}/>;
}

ReactDOM.render( 
  <Img /> ,
  document.getElementById('app')
);
```

```html
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/react@17/umd/react.development.js" crossorigin></script>
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@17/umd/react-dom.development.js" crossorigin></script>

<div id="app"></div>
```

Comment: А если картинок будет много?

Comment: Спасибо за ответ)
Комментатор выше опередил меня: как же все таки быть с несколькими картинками?

Comment: несколько, это сколько?