# Как заранее загрузить определенную группу картинок заранее до их надобности?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

У меня есть определённый массив объектов картинок, и при нажатии кнопки показывается следующий массив картинок. Как можно загрузить заранее следующую группу картинок по их путям тем самым избежать долгой загрузки изображении? Все изображения хранятся в локальной папке, само приложения не имеет бэкенда.

Comment: Например вот так можно "качать" картинки и потом использовать - https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1302146/react-image-onload-image-preload